# Is there any way to make <TabbedShowLayout> as a editable view?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

We have a requirement where we have to use ***edit view*** in place of **show view** in tabbed show layout, something like below image.

[image: Show View]
In react-admin documentation is it clearly stated that **The Show view displays a record fetched from the API in a read-only fashion**

Need suggestions  to achieve this.
Gone through several react-admin documentation did not find any relevant solution.

Answer (score 2):

It was there in documentation

Achieved it using  `<TabbedForm>`

[document](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#the-tabbedform-component)